# Multiple root paths for same Jersey REST API class

Tags: java, rest, web-services, jersey, jax-rs

I have a Jersey REST API class with following root path

```
@Path(/v1/{start}/resource)
public class classA{

//Business logic

}
```

Now I have a requirement where I need to have one more path which points to same REST class, i.e have two paths pointing to same rest class, for example:

Both endpoints `/v1/start/resource` and `/start/resource` should hit the same above given rest class.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Is `{start}` a `@PathParam`?

Comment: @stdunbar Yes, the value can change, based on the URI, i want the beginning parameter i.e. `/v1` to be optional. With or with `/v1` , the URI must hit the same endpoint resource class.

Comment: You can create two end points using the code similar as above. And both the resource layer can call the same internl service

Comment: @DeepakPatankar Not an option, need to have a single class which can resolve to two different endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a solution for this using Regx in the @Path annotation as follows:

```
@Path("/{ver : (v1/)?}{start}/resource")
public class classA{

//Business logic

}
```

The `"/{ver : (v1/)?}{start}/resource"` will resolve to both `/v1/start/resource` or `/start/resource`